# How to back from activity D to A

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, activity-finish

I have 4 activities

A, B, C, D

A is main activity,

B,C,D are listviews

i want do something like this:

go from A -> B -> C -> D

from A start activity B by clicking on button, next start activity C from B by selecting item in ListView, next start activity D by select another item in activity C.
last, when select item in D, go back to activity A and finish activity B and C.

also user should have option to back  when not selecting any item from A <- B
A <- B <- C and A <- B <- C <- D

Could You give me some advice what use to do this: >?

Regards,
swierzy

Comment: Thank all of You very much for answers:) i solved my problem with Your help

Comment: don't forget to mark the appropriate answer! just click the checkbox next to the answer that worked for you

Answer (score 3):

If you are done in one Activity, call `finish()`.
To detect if a child activity has returned implement `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Does onActivityResult know to restart the activity if it has been finished?

Comment: Start activity C and D with startActivityWithResult(). On activity D, when something is picked call `setResult(data)` followed by `finish()`. Then do the same in the `onActivityResult()` on C, if D finished successfully, call `setResult()` then `finish()`.

Comment: @dymmeh Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: You start activity B by calling startActivityForResult from within activity A. You call finish() on activity A when you run this intent. Activity A no longer is running. You press back on activity B. The expected result would be to restart activity A. However, you called finish on this activity already. Does activity A know to restart in order to handle the onActivityResult?

Comment: @dymmeh It was destroyed, so it will not automatically be here again! Hihi.

Comment: Ok I originally misunderstood your logic and it was making me think that there would be a problem with it. All good now! :) cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For A, B, and C, you'll want to invoke `startActivityForResult()`. This allows you to be notified when the launched `Activity` is complete.

From A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, B_ACTIVITY);

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == B_ACTIVITY)) {
        // handle success
    }
}
```

From B (and similarly from C)

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivityForResult(i, C_ACTIVITY);

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == C_ACTIVITY)) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

When you're done in D, call `setResult(RESULT_OK);` then `finish()` and everything will happen as you desire. The Back button will be handled correctly automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent and capture the back button:

for instance, from B to A

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(B.this,A.class);
            B.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

Comment: The back button should work properly by default, and its generally not a good idea to override it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want go from D to A, use intent to call A and set the flag http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP on the intent (intent.setFlag()).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(D.this, A.class);
intent.setFlag(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

To go back from B to A, C to B..., use only onBackPressed. The method onBackPressed finish the current activity and you come back to the activity A automatically. Don't override onBackPressed method !

```
private void onClickBackButton() {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

See the FLAG information on developers android site : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT